# How to set up Apache Kafka Broker with Client-side Authentication through Docker (Azure)

Tags: azure, docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to set up a Kafka Broker so that a client can send data to us real-time. This broker will run in a Docker Container in Azure. I've gotten the Broker set up and running without authentication, but when I try to add the client-side Authentication to the compose.yaml my broker ends up in a constantly restarting state.

The setup that I have been using.

docker-compose.yaml (deployed to azure through cmd)

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: [ContainerIp]
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://[ContainerIp]:9096,SASL_PLAINTEXT://[ContainerIp]:9092'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://[ContainerIp]:9096,SASL_PLAINTEXT://[ContainerIp]:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: 'SASL_PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: 'SASL_PLAINTEXT'
    volumes:
      - kafkaconfig:/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf

volumes:
  kafkaconfig:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: [azureshare]
      storage_account_name: [shareaccount]
      storage_account_key: [accountkey]
```

kafka_server_jaas.conf (stored in azure file share)

```
KafkaServer {
};

KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="Admin" \
    password="Password";
};
```

consumer.py (run locally)

```
import json 
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Kafka Consumer 
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        'pumpdatalive',
        bootstrap_servers='[ContainerIP]:9092',
        auto_offset_reset='earliest',
        sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
        sasl_plain_username='Admin',
        sasl_plain_password='Password',
        security_protocol = "PLAINTEXT"
    )
    for message in consumer:
        print(json.loads(message.value))
```

producer.py (run locally)

```
import time 
import json 
import random 
from datetime import datetime
from data_generator import generate_message
from kafka import KafkaProducer

# Messages will be serialized as JSON 
def serializer(message):
    return json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')

# Kafka Producer
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=['[ContainerIP]:9092'],
    value_serializer=serializer,
    sasl_mechanism='PLAIN',
    sasl_plain_username='Admin',
    sasl_plain_password='Password',
    security_protocol = "PLAINTEXT"
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Infinite loop - runs until you kill the program
    while True:
        # Generate a message
        dummy_message = generate_message()
        
        # Send it to our 'messages' topic
        print(f'Producing message @ {datetime.now()} | Message = {str(dummy_message)}')
        producer.send('pumpdatalive', dummy_message)
        
        # Sleep for a random number of seconds
        time_to_sleep = random.randint(1, 11)
        time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
```

Comment: `KafkaServer` JAAS section cannot be empty... Just use EventHubs and enable Kafka support mode.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Just getting back to this in earnest. I have several questions about this comment:

Does the client need to do anything at all different with their connector in order to send data to an EventHub?
Does the EventHub just act as a broker, or is it a broker and a consumer?
If the JAAS KafkaServer section cannot be empty, what do I do if I do not want broker to broker authentication and I only want broker to client authentication?

Comment: EventHubs is a broker, hosted in Azure without using Docker. You still need separate client configurations to use it, including valid JAAS configs. There is a Java client example in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quickstart-kafka-enabled-event-hubs?tabs=passwordless But my point was that `KafkaClient` JAAS section isn't needed for the broker **server** file, and `KafkaServer` section would be needed https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/security_tutorial.html#configure-brokers

Comment: @OneCricketeer We have a customer who is using Kafka for their integrations with another company, and I have zero control over how the KafkaClient gets set up. The Customer will not do anything differently than what they are already doing, so if they need to change how they are setting up Producers in order to connect to EventHubs, this path is a nonstarter.

Comment: Okay. I don't understand how that's related to your Docker setup then, which could effectively create a brand new Kafka server, not use any existing one? My point is that not using Docker would be "more supported", and offer better access/network controls in the VNET policies

Comment: @OneCricketeer My company does not use Kafka currently. I have been tasked with figuring out how to stand up a KafkaBroker in order to integrate the data from our customer. 
Using Docker would eliminate the need to stand up and manage a new VM for Kafka.

Comment: And you need to use Docker instead of EventHubs support for it? Or instead of running AKS with Strimzi? Or other vendor solutions like Aiven / Confluent Cloud, linked to your Azure Account? More specifically, you have no data volumes mounted on your container, so restarting those would lose everything. And upgrades would be problematic in the future. Using hosted solutions means you don't have to worry about that, and it'll likely be secure by default, rather than defining your own configs

Comment: @OneCricketeer you are trying to educate, and I am trying to learn, but I do not have the reputation to be able to move this to a chat and the comments are not the place for this. So, I will ask this one last question:

Is the KafkaClient setup going to be the same for our customer whether we stand up a EventHubs namespace or a KafkaServer?

Comment: Yes. It will be. The fact that you have setup EventHubs should be transparent. Again, see the Kafka example shown in the EventHubs docs (or [Python example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/quickstart/python)) and compare to other more official Kafka documentation